# How to set Response Header in Spring Security xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I wanna modify value of "Server" in response header. I try to fix that in java code. But that's work just in 200 response. 
Can I set it on springsecurity.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a value to response header?

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <headers>
            <header name="Server" value="Lius"/>
...
        </headers>
...
</http>
```

Comment: how can I modify cookie value in headers ?

Comment: <header name="Set-Cookie" value="Server=Lius"/>